# Making Tiny Wings like Game using Sprite Kit

Tags: ios, sprite-kit

Does anyone have any experience with this? I have been using SKSpriteNodes using BezierPaths as half circles for the hills (and physicsBody), then loading them off of the screen, and moving them by 1-10 pixels per frame update to the left.

It's laggy, the camera doesn't follow the bird, the bird never gets enough speed to actually go up a hill on its own...

I tried to use SKActions to move the hills to the left of the screen, but then they didn't always line up to the exact pixel, and the bird ended up falling inbetween them sometimes.

Is there a better way than this? Having 4 half circle SKSpriteNodes, moving left, at a fixed rate? I wish I could get the bird to stay at a fixed x position on the screen, and only move the hills left at appropriate times.

Here is my code for creating hills

```
- (void) createNewHill {
// Hill 1
SKSpriteNode *hill = [[SKSpriteNode alloc] initWithColor:[UIColor clearColor] size:CGSizeMake([UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.width * 2, [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.height * 0.5)];
SKSpriteNode *lastHill = [hillArray objectAtIndex:(hillArray.count - 1)];
[hill setPosition:CGPointMake(lastHill.frame.origin.x + lastHill.frame.size.width, hill.frame.size.height * 0.5)];

float x1 = -hill.frame.size.width / 2;
float x3 = -hill.frame.size.width / 4;
float x7 = hill.frame.size.width / 4;
float x9 = hill.frame.size.width / 2;
float y1 = - hill.frame.size.height / 2;
float y5 = hill.frame.size.height / 2;

UIBezierPath* bezierPath = [UIBezierPath bezierPath];
[bezierPath moveToPoint: CGPointMake(x1, 0)];
[bezierPath addQuadCurveToPoint:CGPointMake(0, 0) controlPoint:CGPointMake(x3, y1 * 2)];
[bezierPath addQuadCurveToPoint:CGPointMake(x9, 0) controlPoint:CGPointMake(x7, y5 * 2)];
[bezierPath addLineToPoint:CGPointMake(x9, y1)];
[bezierPath addLineToPoint:CGPointMake(x1, y1)];
[bezierPath closePath];

[hill setPhysicsBody:[SKPhysicsBody bodyWithEdgeLoopFromPath:bezierPath.CGPath]];
hill.physicsBody.dynamic = NO;
hill.physicsBody.friction = 0;
hill.physicsBody.restitution = 0;

// Hill 2
SKSpriteNode *hill2 = [[SKSpriteNode alloc] initWithColor:[UIColor clearColor] size:CGSizeMake([UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.width * 2, [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.height * 0.5)];
[hill2 setPosition:CGPointMake(hill.position.x + hill2.frame.size.width, hill.position.y)];
[hill2 setPhysicsBody:[SKPhysicsBody bodyWithEdgeLoopFromPath:bezierPath.CGPath]];
hill2.physicsBody.dynamic = NO;
hill2.physicsBody.friction = 0;
hill2.physicsBody.restitution = 0;

[scene addChild:hill];
[scene addChild:hill2];
[hillArray addObject:hill];
[hillArray addObject:hill2]; }
```

And here is a portion of my code that is run off a timer (repeats every 1.0/60.0 second)

```
SKSpriteNode *firstHill = [hillArray objectAtIndex:0];
    SKSpriteNode *secondHill = [hillArray objectAtIndex:1];

    if (speedOfHills < 60 * 10)
        speedOfHills++;
    [firstHill setPosition:CGPointMake(firstHill.position.x - [self getDoubleBasedOnDevice:speedOfHills / 60 :speedOfHills / 60 :speedOfHills / 30], firstHill.position.y)];
    for (int i = 1; i < hillArray.count; i++)
    {
        SKSpriteNode *thisHill = [hillArray objectAtIndex:i];
        SKSpriteNode *previousHill = [hillArray objectAtIndex:i - 1];
        [thisHill setPosition:CGPointMake(previousHill.position.x + (previousHill.frame.size.width / 2) + (thisHill.frame.size.width / 2), firstHill.position.y)];
    }

    if (firstHill.position.x < - ((firstHill.size.width / 2) + (secondHill.frame.size.width)) * 1.05)
    {
        [self createNewHill];
        [firstHill removeFromParent];
        [secondHill removeFromParent];
        [hillArray removeObjectAtIndex:1];
        [hillArray removeObjectAtIndex:0];
    }
```

I've tried a few things so far, but this is just my current timerUpdate setup.

Comment: Can you post some code where you're creating the hills, animate them, etc.?

Comment: Okie dokie, added it. Is that enough?

Comment: Cocos2d is a better choice for making a game like Tiny Wings, at least visually because the smoothly curved hills look better when drawn with custom OpenGL. Here's a tutorial: http://www.raywenderlich.com/32954/how-to-create-a-game-like-tiny-wings-with-cocos2d-2-x-part-1

Answer (score 1):

If you are using a timer to update those positions you are doing sprite kit wrong. Read about the update loop

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/GraphicsAnimation/Conceptual/SpriteKit_PG/Introduction/Introduction.html

You should be moving your hills and things in your `SKScene`'s `- (void)update:(NSTimeInterval)currentTime` method. You get the current time as part of the method. If you want to move things yourself so they line up with pixels you need to move things in this method. You can use the classic formula speed = distance / time to figure out how far to move your hills. If you know the speed then distance = speed * time. Time elapsed is the difference between the time at this update and the time of the last one.

I recommend finding and running through some sprite kit tutorials

Comment: Does it make a difference? I tried it before and seemed like it did the same thing as using a timer